# Class with mandatory parameter

Tags: c#-3.0

i have some mandatory fields and when calling the constructor of my class i got null reference exception, how prevent this please.

```
new Part(Partitems["Name"].ToString(), Partitems["Logo"].ToString(), Partitems["Description"].ToString(), Partitems["URL"].ToString()));
```

> MY Class :

```
public class Part
    {
        string _Name= string.Empty;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }
```

...
..

**EDIT**
Here is constructor code

```
public Part(string Name, string Logo, string Description, string URL) 
{ 
    this.Name = Name; 
    this.Logo = Logo; 
    this.Description = Description; 
    this.URL = URL; 
}
```

Comment: ... you just left out the most important bit - your constructor.

Comment: public Part(string Name, string Logo, string Description, string URL)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Logo = Logo;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.URL = URL;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the constructor that could cause a null reference exception, as assigning null to a string property is perfectly valid. So, either your `Partitems` variable is null, or one of it's properties returns null.

Example for handling both situations:

```
if (Partitems != null) {
  object name = Partitems["Name"] ?? String.Empty;
  object logo = Partitems["Logo"] ?? String.Empty;
  object description = Partitems["Description"] ?? String.Empty;
  object url = Partitems["URL"] ?? String.Empty;
  part = new Part(name.ToString(), logo.ToString(), description.ToString(), url.ToString()));
} else {
  // Oops, Partitems is null. Better tell the user or log the error...
}
```

This will replace any null values in the properties with empty strings. However, you might want to handle it as an error situation instead, depending on the situation.

Comment: thx, but if i got 20 fields, i have to check every item if its null or not ?

Comment: @markov00: Yes, if you want to handle null reference for each value, you have to check every single value.

Answer (score 2):

may be one of this properties

```
Partitems["Name"], Partitems["Logo"],Partitems["Description"],Partitems["URL"]
```

is null? Your constructor code will help to understand problem more...

Comment: public Part(string Name, string Logo, string Description, string URL)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Logo = Logo;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.URL = URL;
        }

Comment: than probably one or more of mentioned properties are null

Comment: yes if the field is mondatory i got a null value but how to prevent this thx